# An example of series such that $0\le a_n\le b_n$ and $\sum a_n$ converges but $\sum b_n$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Looking to get some help with the following question.

I need to find nonnegative sequences $(a_n)$and $(b_n)$ such that $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n$ and $\sum a_n$ converges but $\sum b_n$ diverges.

So the terms of $a_n$ must turn to $0$ but $b_n$ does not. But how do I find examples of this series?

Comment: @Arrow thank you for the edit

Comment: @SimpleArt sorry I had a typo there, just made a edit

Comment: But it's not a question.

Comment: Why can't $b_{n}$ tend to zero?  These terms can still constitute a divergent series.  For example:
$$
a_{n} = {1 \over n^2}, \quad b_{n} = {1 \over n}.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if $a_n=\frac1{2^n}$ and $b_n=n$, then

$$a_n\le b_n$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}=1<+\infty$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=+\infty$$

But it is not necessary for $\require{cancel}b_n\cancel\to0$, for example, with $b_n=\frac1n$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n>\int_1^\infty\frac1x\ dx=\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln(t)=+\infty$$

But it is necessary for $a_n\to0$ by the [term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Comment: no I understand this now, thanks

Comment: @mp12345 I updated, including avs's hint, in case you were wondering if it were necessary that $a_n$ and $b_n$ behave the way you predicted.

Comment: thanks again for your help

Comment: @mp12345 No problem :-)